# jQuery, send textarea value of rich text editor with ajax?

Tags: jquery, rich-text-editor, elrte

I couldn't post the textarea value with ajax in **elRTE** rich text editor.

The editor demo page is like below;

http://elrte.org/demo

and I use the code below;

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    url: "forms.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html"
});

$("input.add").live("click", function(){
    $.ajax({
        data: {action: 'add', tag: $('input.tag').val(), description: $('#editor').val()},
        success: function(data){
            $("#message").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I have tried couple of different ways to send the textarea value, but couldn't achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just taking a quick look at your demo page I notice that your `#editor "textarea"` is not actually a textarea, it's a `DIV` made to look like a text area. So `$('#editor').val()` wont work. I would suggest using `$('#editor').html()` instead but `#editor` isn't the actual editor div, so that won't actually get you where you want to be. Shyju's answer gets it right with selecting the actual div and using `.html()` to get the contact.

But I just looked at the site a bit further and there appears to be a javascript api that allows you to easily get the data you want: **`$('#editor').elrte('val');`** 
http://elrte.org/redmine/projects/elrte/wiki/JavaScript_API_EN

Another problem that you may run into is that you're currently doing your **ajax** request via `GET` (the default method), but since the description value could be very large it could be too big for the URL's maximum length restriction. I would suggest using `POST` instead of `GET` for your ajax request instead. Ie: **type: "`POST`"**

Comment: this is the answer for me :). I edited my post, I have already used post method in ajax with ajaxSetup, but thanks for noticing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I could see the div has a class named "`el-rt-structure`". Try selecting the element using that and get the inner html of that using html() function

```
$("input.add").live("click", function(){
  var textAreContent=$(".el-rte-structure").html();
    $.ajax({
        data: {action: 'add', tag: $('input.tag').val(), description: textAreContent},
        success: function(data){
            $("#message").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried this way, but didn't work. I think this is because of iframe. thanks.